# How can I find multiple items in a List<>

Tags: c#, .net, list, find

I have this `List<Employee>` in the class`EmployeesController.cs`, and this list contains the data and the  information about the employees. That `List<>` save every entry that class `EmployeesController.cs` sends to every property in `Employees` class.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int IdEmployee { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Double Salary { get; set; }
    public Job WorkStation { get; set; }
    public Department Section { get; set; }
}
```

Job and Apartment are another objects. Each employee has an apartment assigned.

I want an option in my program: search by using the department assigned to each employee.

And I want to find the employees whose have the same apartment assigned. I want the `List<Employees>` to return a set of employees with the same department.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `list.Where(e => e.Section.Name = "Engineering Department")`

Comment: DavidG meant: var list2 =  list.Where(e => e.Section.Name == "Engineering Department").ToList();

Comment: i really appreciate it, thanks @ipavlu

Comment: And @DavidG, It was very useful

Answer (score 3):

You don't show your `Department` class here, but if you have an instance of `Department` and you want to find `Employee` objects that are members of that department, you could do something like:

```
// Assuming you have some way to get all employees
List<Employee> allEmployees = SomeMethod.GetAllEmployees();

// Assuming you have a department you want to find employees in
Department hrDepartment = new Department { Name = "HumanResources" };

// You can do something like this to get all employees in the HR department
List<Employee> hrEmployees = allEmployees.Where(e => 
    e.Department.Name.Equals(hrDepartment.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: Minor point: you have to do `.ToList()` at the end. Excellent answer otherwise.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Thanks! That's what I get for answering from my phone. Fixed.